# Posh Git Won't Show Status or Colors on Prompt

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I'm on Windows 7, installed git and then posh-git (to run git from powershell), no errors. I'm able to enter git commands like 'git init' and 'git status' now from the powershell, and posh-git's tab completion works in my powershell, so I believe means posh-git was installed successfully.

However, according to posh-git documentation, my powershell prompt should now provide 'git status' info with colors (like [master] when my directory has a .git file), but it doesn't. I ran $GitPromptSettings (which I found on posh-git's github readme) but "EnablePromptStatus" is True, and I don't see any other options in the GitPromptSettings that it looks like I should change to enable the prompt status.

My current directory in powershell has a .git folder in it, from a 'git init' command I entered in powershell, so I can't figure out why posh-git's PromptStatus feature isn't reflected in my powershell prompt.

Comment: Go here and file a bug:
https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues

And if you're in a good mood, you can fix it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks Vivek, done. Although I don't think I'd be much help trying to fix it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Git Bash for a while on Windowws 7, and initially I faced the same errors. The reason then was that the signature of my machine was not validated at the server. 
So, essentially all that I had to do is generate a signature using Git Bash which will be stored in .ssh  directory, copy the same into clipboard. Then, open up profile on github, or any git repository client you are using in web browser, go to your profile, and under add signature tab, paste the signature that you had generated. 
This worked for me. Not sure if this is the same issue that you are facing, but thought of sharing my experience (incase you get any further ideas!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is still needing an answer but I was experiencing something similar to the poster. I just added the directory where posh git was installed to my environment variables and it started working. For my the directory was "C:\tools\poshgit"